# Evaluate this complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis

Let u and v be the real and imaginary parts of the function f(z)=1/(z^2-6z+8). C is |z|=3 counterclockwise. Evaluate   $\int $ udy+vdx over C.

My attempt: I was trying to apply greens theorem by writing f(z) in terms of x and y. But i think it will not work as for greens theorem u and v must have first order partial derivative exists and continuous. U and v doesn't exist at (2,0).

Another attempt is$ \int $f(z)dz =$\int $ (u+iv) d(x+iy)
=    $\int $ (u+iv) dx+idv
=  $\int $ udx -vdy +i     $\int $ udy +vdx (after multiplication)

Now applying cauchys integral formula   $\int $ g(z)/(z-2) dz =g(2)*2*$ \pi $ * i= $ \pi $* i
I cant proceed further.  Where g(z) =1/(z-4) .Also please elaborate how can i apply greens theorem.

Please let me know what i have to apply in this problem?

Comment: Please format the question in MathJax so it is readable.

Comment: What is mathjax?

Comment: I am not using any device in which i can put mathematical symbols. Please suggest me how can i put symbo

Comment: @BePure See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Tnank you @mathcounterexamples

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt is the way to go and you are almost done. So, there is no need to find explicit expressions for $u$ and $v$.

Denoting the imaginary part of a complex number $\zeta$ by $\Im(\zeta)$, you found already that

$$\int_{x^2+y^2=9}u\,dy + v\,dx = \Im\left(\int_{|z|=3}\frac 1{z^2-6z+8}dz\right)$$

Now, as you already did, applying the Cauchy integral formula you get

\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{|z|=3}\frac 1{z^2-6z+8}dz
& = & \int_{|z|=3}\frac 1{(z-2)(z-4)}dz \\
& = & \int_{|z|=3}\frac{\frac 1{z-4}}{z-2}dz \\ 
& \stackrel{Cauchy}{=} & 2\pi i \frac 1{2-4} \\
& = &-\pi i
\end{eqnarray*}

Hence,

$$\int_{x^2+y^2=9}u\,dy + v\,dx = \Im(-\pi i) = -\pi$$

Comment: Thank you very very very very very very very very very much.

Comment: @BePure You are very very very welcome :-)

Comment: @BePure If you are fine with my answer you may tag it as accepted.

Comment: You mean this as accepted? Upvote? I don't know how to tag.

Comment: You have the possibility to "accept" an answer. Then it gets a green tag and people can see that the question has an accepted answer.

Comment: @BePure : But of course if you think that the answer is also helpful and/or nice, you can also upvote it to show your appreciation.

Comment: Yeah, i upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* Only one of the poles of the integrand is inside the circle of interest. Thus you only need to find the residue of the integrand at the pole of interest, and then the integral is just $2πi\times \text{residue of interest}.$

Comment: I haven't clear understanding of residue, pole, singularity now. But i have a vague understanding of it. What i know about pole is if f(z) is a polynomial and m is a root of it then 1/f(z) have a pole at m.